# Как добавить данные из дополнительного потока в основной поток, т.е. в интерфейс для их отображения?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, qthread, qtextedit

```
class External(QThread):
    countChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url
        self.sql(url)

    def sql(self,url):
        lines = open(file, "r")
        lines = lines.readlines()
        lines.close()
        for line in lines:
            self.textChanged.emit("text")
```

Хочу из потока добавить текст в контрол, но появляется две проблемы:

1. Форма зависает напрочь.
2. Текст не добавляется.

Однако если я вместо `self.calc.start()` сделаю `self.calc.sql("url")`, то данные на форме появляются, но форма также подвисает.

```
def onButtonClick(self):
    self.calc = External(self.urlbox.toPlainText())
    self.calc.countChanged.connect(self.onCountChanged)
    self.calc.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
    self.calc.start()

def onCountChanged(self, value):
    self.progress.setValue(value)

def onTextChanged(self, value):
    self.log.insertPlainText(value)
    self.log.ensureCursorVisible()
```

---

Полный листинг:

```
import sys
import time
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import time
import os
import certifi
import pycurl

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog,QProgressBar, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QTextEdit,QRadioButton)


TIME_LIMIT = 100

class External(QThread):
    countChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url
    
    def run(self):                              # +++
        self.sql(url)

    def sql(self,url):
        dir1 = str(Path().resolve())
        file = os.path.join(dir1,'sqlpayload.txt')
        logilfe = os.path.join(dir1,'log.txt')

        sqlDosya = open(file, "r")
        sqlPayload = sqlDosya.readlines()
        sqlDosya.close()
        index = 0
        if "=" in url:
            deger = str(url).find('=')
            for i in sqlPayload:
                index+=1
                self.countChanged.emit(index)
                try:
                    i = i.split("\n")[0]
                    yazi = str(url[0:deger + 1]) + str(i)
                    sonuc = requests.get(yazi)
                    if int(sonuc.status_code)==200:
                        # self.log.append("[+]Sqli paylaod: ", str(i))
                        self.textChanged.emit("[+]Sqli paylaod: "+ str(i)+"\n")
                        print ("[+]Sqli paylaod: ", str(i))

                        self.textChanged.emit("[+]Sqli URL: ", yazi+"\n")
                        print ("[+]Sqli URL: ", yazi)
                        rapor=open(logilfe,"a")
                        raporIcerik="[+]Sqli paylaod: "+str(i)+"\n"
                        raporIcerik+="[+]Sqli URL: "+yazi+"\n"
                        rapor.write(raporIcerik)
                        rapor.close()
                    else:
                        self.textChanged.emit("[-]Sqli paylaod: "+ str(i)+"\n")
                        print ("[-]Sqli paylaod: ", str(i))

                        self.textChanged.emit("[-]Sqli URL: "+ yazi+"\n")
                        print ("[-]Sqli URL: ", yazi)
                        
                        rapor=open(logilfe,"a")
                        raporIcerik="[-]Sqli paylaod: "+str(i)+"\n"
                        raporIcerik+="[-]Sqli URL: "+yazi+"\n"
                        rapor.write(raporIcerik)
                        rapor.close()
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            self.textChanged.emit("[-]Sqli isn't available"+"\n")

            print ("[-]Sqli isn't available")
            rapor = open(logilfe, "a")
            raporIcerik = "[-]Sqli isn't available\n"
            rapor.write(raporIcerik)
            rapor.close()
    
class Actions(QDialog):
    """
    Simple dialog that consists of a Progress Bar and a Button.
    Clicking on the button results in the start of a timer and
    updates the progress bar.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')
        
        self.urlbox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.urlbox.setText("https://xss-game.appspot.com/level1/frame?query=asd")
        self.urlbox.setGeometry(5, 0, 465, 25)

        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(5, 30, 500, 25)
        self.progress.setMaximum(100)

        self.log = QTextEdit(self)
        self.log.move(5, 60)
        self.log.setGeometry(5, 60, 465, 200)

        self.button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.button.move(5, 270)

        self.xssradio = QRadioButton("xss",self)
        self.xssradio.setChecked(1)
        self.xssradio.move(100, 273)

        self.sqliradio = QRadioButton("sqli",self)
        self.sqliradio.move(150, 273)

        self.show()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        self.calc = External(self.urlbox.toPlainText())
        self.calc.countChanged.connect(self.onCountChanged)
        self.calc.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        self.calc.sql(self.urlbox.toPlainText())

    def onCountChanged(self, value):
        self.progress.setValue(value)
    
    def onTextChanged(self, value):
        self.log.insertPlainText(value)
        self.log.ensureCursorVisible()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Actions()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый приме, который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
...
class External(QThread):
    countChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url
#        self.sql(url)

    def run(self):                              # +++
        self.sql(self.url)                      # + self.url

    def sql(self, url):
        lines = open(file, "r")
        lines = lines.readlines()
        lines.close()
        for line in lines:
            self.textChanged.emit("text")
...
```

---

**Update**

Основная ваша ошибка в неправильном вызове/старте дополнительного потока, который запускается `self.calc.start()`, что приводит к автоматическому запуску метода `def run(self):`, который вызовет метод `def sql(self, url):` командой `self.sql(self.url)`. Обратите внимание, передается параметр `self.url`, а не `url`.

Я также добавил некоторые микро паузы `self.msleep(5)` в 5 ms, чтобы CPU не залипало на 100%.

Подставьте свой 'sqlpayload.txt' и попробуйте:

```
import sys
import time
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import time
import os
import certifi
#import pycurl

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog,QProgressBar, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QTextEdit,QRadioButton)

TIME_LIMIT = 100

class External(QThread):
    countChanged = pyqtSignal(int)
    textChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.url = url


    def run(self):        
#        self.sql(url)                                              # ---  НЕТ
        self.sql(self.url)                                          # +++  self.url !!!


    def sql(self, url):
        dir1 = str(Path().resolve())

#        file = os.path.join(dir1,'sqlpayload.txt')   # ! 'sqlpayload.txt' установите свой .txt
        file = os.path.join(dir1,'test.txt')          # ! 'test.txt'

        logilfe = os.path.join(dir1,'log.txt')

        sqlDosya = open(file, "r")
        sqlPayload = sqlDosya.readlines()
        sqlDosya.close()
        index = 0
        if "=" in url:
            deger = str(url).find('=')
            for i in sqlPayload:
                index += 1

                self.countChanged.emit(index)
                self.msleep(5)                                                    # +++

                try:
                    i = i.split("\n")[0]
                    yazi = str(url[0:deger + 1]) + str(i)
                    sonuc = requests.get(yazi)
                    if int(sonuc.status_code)==200:
                        # self.log.append("[+]Sqli paylaod: ", str(i))
                        self.textChanged.emit("[+]Sqli paylaod: "+ str(i)+"\n")
#                        print ("[+]Sqli paylaod: ", str(i))
                        self.msleep(5)

                        self.textChanged.emit("[+]Sqli URL: ", yazi+"\n")
#                        print ("[+]Sqli URL: ", yazi)
                        self.msleep(5)

                        rapor=open(logilfe,"a")
                        raporIcerik="[+]Sqli paylaod: "+str(i)+"\n"
                        raporIcerik+="[+]Sqli URL: "+yazi+"\n"
                        rapor.write(raporIcerik)
                        rapor.close()
                    else:
                        self.textChanged.emit("[-]Sqli paylaod: "+ str(i)+"\n")
#                        print ("[-]Sqli paylaod: ", str(i))
                        self.msleep(5)

                        self.textChanged.emit("[-]Sqli URL: "+ yazi+"\n")
#                        print ("[-]Sqli URL: ", yazi)
                        self.msleep(5)

                        rapor=open(logilfe,"a")
                        raporIcerik="[-]Sqli paylaod: "+str(i)+"\n"
                        raporIcerik+="[-]Sqli URL: "+yazi+"\n"
                        rapor.write(raporIcerik)
                        rapor.close()
                except:
                    pass
        else:
            self.textChanged.emit("[-]Sqli isn't available"+"\n")

#            print ("[-]Sqli isn't available")
            rapor = open(logilfe, "a")
            raporIcerik = "[-]Sqli isn't available\n"
            rapor.write(raporIcerik)
            rapor.close()


class Actions(QDialog):
    """
    Simple dialog that consists of a Progress Bar and a Button.
    Clicking on the button results in the start of a timer and
    updates the progress bar.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')

        self.urlbox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.urlbox.setText("https://xss-game.appspot.com/level1/frame?query=asd")
        self.urlbox.setGeometry(5, 0, 465, 25)

        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(5, 30, 500, 25)
        self.progress.setMaximum(100)

        self.log = QTextEdit(self)
        self.log.move(5, 60)
        self.log.setGeometry(5, 60, 465, 200)

        self.button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.button.move(5, 270)

        self.xssradio = QRadioButton("xss",self)
        self.xssradio.setChecked(1)
        self.xssradio.move(100, 273)

        self.sqliradio = QRadioButton("sqli",self)
        self.sqliradio.move(150, 273)

        self.show()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        self.calc = External(self.urlbox.toPlainText())
        self.calc.countChanged.connect(self.onCountChanged)
        self.calc.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)

#        self.calc.sql(self.urlbox.toPlainText())                       # --- НЕТ
        self.calc.start()                                               # +++ start() !!!


    def onCountChanged(self, value):
        self.progress.setValue(value)

    def onTextChanged(self, value):
        self.log.insertPlainText(value)
        self.log.ensureCursorVisible()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Actions()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Форма подвисает на месте. Единственное что изменилось - данные вижу уже на форме. Но всё равно, форма виснет и кроме как смотреть на данные ничего не получается))

Comment: @Radzhab предоставьте минимально-воспроизводимый приме, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: полный листинг..

Comment: Какие будут идеи-мысли?

Comment: @Radzhab  я попробую посмотреть ваш пример чуть позже.

Comment: @Radzhab я добавил обновление, пробуйте.